# salesforce - report permission issue data missing

Tags: security, salesforce, cloud, crm

Depending on the user, report data is missing when viewed via the dashboard.

-In security settings I gave organization-wide read/write permission.
-The reports are based on a two custom data objects with a master/child relationship (which is also set as read/write.)

-The report folder is also set as "read/write" and all users have permission.

Anything else that I forgot to check?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What error do you experience? "Insufficient privileges"? Or maybe report loads fine but just shows 0 rows?

When drilling down to the detailed report you need to make sure that

1. viewing user has at least Read permission in his Profile on both the master and child object
2. he must also has read permission to all fields used in the report (columns as well as filters. And if any of them is a formula -> check their source fields too).
3. Does the report use "My Opportunities" in the filters? Or unrealistic date criteria? If the dashboard wasn't refreshed in a while even date filters can cause you grief.
4. In some cases the Roles hierarchy is saved with the report - if the user sits in different branch of the role hierarchy than the dashboard's running user, you might have to flip it to your top level Role for example. Run the report, examine top part for Role names, adapt if needed and save it.

Perhaps the best way is to debug it is to login as this user and try to recreate this report from scratch. If you can't even select proper report type - this looks like scenario 1. If fields are missing - 2.